# ROC Curve using plotROC package and geom_roc(), transforming data to "M1 markers"

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc

I am attempting to plot a ROC curve using the [`plotROC`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotROC/vignettes/examples.html) package for `ggplot2`, but I am not sure how to transform the data I have into the `M1` marker format. The documentation provided the following example:

```
# plotROC documentation example
library(plotROC)
library(ggplot2)
D.ex <- rbinom(200, size = 1, prob = .5)
M1 <- rnorm(200, mean = D.ex, sd = .65)
M2 <- rnorm(200, mean = D.ex, sd = 1.5)

D         M1         M2
1  1.4995932  0.5508204
1  0.4181619  1.6339181
0 -0.3620614 -1.0428972
1  0.7991132 -1.6396751
0  0.9574047  2.1159753
1  1.3440595  1.3026485

test <- data.frame(D = D.ex, D.str = c("Healthy", "Ill")[D.ex + 1], 
               M1 = M1, M2 = M2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(test, aes(d = D, m = M1)) + 
   geom_roc()
```

[Sample ROC plot output by plotROC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af44G.png)

My data is logistic regression scores on a test subset:

```
# Example starting point
test <- rbinom(200, size = 1, prob = 0.2)
scores.prob <- runif(200, min = 0 , max = 1)
scores.class <- ifelse(scores.prob > 0.5, 1, 0)

# Example generated data
test scores.prob scores.class
 0   0.7323306            1
 0   0.7860687            1
 0   0.9535123            1
 1   0.3082551            0
 0   0.5762784            1
 1   0.4613730            0
```

I would like to know what `M1` is and how to transform my data to get that field.

Comment: I don't really understand it, but this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3952000/ has a whole bunch about ROC curves, M1 and M2. Could that help?

Comment: also check out the `?StatRoc` page as it goes into a bit more detail about the d and m parameters

Comment: @user10626943 `?StatRoc` was a great resource! Thank you for the fast response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(plotROC) 
library(ggplot2) 
test <- rbinom(200, size = 1, prob = 0.2)
scores.prob <- runif(200, min = 0 , max = 1) 
test <- data.frame(D = test,
           M1 = scores.prob, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggplot(test, aes(d = D, m = M1)) + 
geom_roc()
```

Your marker/predictor is the fitted values of your glm model. The ROC will give you the idea of how your model work (by means of AUC) and the best probability threshold (the ROC cutoff) for assigning persons to classes.
It is a usefull approach if you want to visualize the added value of fdifferent multivariate/univariate approaches.
Here a full example with the mtcars dataset. Hope it helps.

```
# Loading data
data(mtcars)
# Manual transmission (am = 1) depends on 1/4 mile time (qsec) and miles/(US) gallon (mpg)
glmfit <- glm(am ~ qsec + mpg, data = mtcars, binomial)
mtcars$fitted_am <- glmfit$fitted.values
# Loading packages
library(plotROC)
library(ggplot2)
library(pROC)
# Calculating ROC curve, AUC and threshold according to Youden index
rocfit <- roc(mtcars$am, mtcars$fitted_am)
auc(rocfit)
coords(rocfit, x = "b")
basicplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(d = am, m = fitted_am))
basicplot + 
  geom_roc() + 
  style_roc(theme = theme_grey) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "blue")) +
  ggtitle("Automatic transmission prediction") +
  scale_x_continuous("1 - Specificity", breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .1))
plot(rocfit)
prop.table(table(mtcars$am))
```